# Graphene: customizing how Enum is serialized

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django, graphene-sqlalchemy

Our backend uses SQLAlchemy as our ORM, and I've recently been playing around with exposing a graphql API, but am having a hard time figuring out how to customize how `Enum` is serialized by graphene.

Our SqlAlchemy objects all inherit from a `BaseModel` we've written, and we've created our own `BaseEnum` that all `db.Enum` fields inherit, which we use to customize the fields included in a payload to the client, which is as follows,

```
someEnum: {
    'value': <some_value>,
    'label': <some_label>,
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to get graphene to do the same serialization (or if it is even possible/violates the spirit of grapqhl). Since these `Enums` are stored in our database as strings like `THE_ENUM_VALUE`, this is all graphene returns.

So I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is this even the correct way to return this kind of payload with graphql? Or would it be more proper to have a query like

```
{
  someModel {
    someEnum {
      label
      value
    }
  }
}
```

2. How would I override the serialization of *all* `Enum` fields returned by graphene so we don't have to write custom resolvers for every single `Enum` field? (there are hundreds)

Answer (score 0):

For everyone looking for an answer for the second question:

```py
class MyEnum(graphene.Enum,):
    value: <some_value>,
    label: <some_label>,

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self.value
```